# Image SRC not well formed tag

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, html

I'm trying to print all photos in a list using a repeater 
and I got error that a tag is not well formed

I tried different ways and it still gives me an error

```
 <img  runat="server" src='http://p rod:82/en/Colleges/Gallary/<% ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Name"] %>' />


  <img  runat="server" src="http://p rod:82/en/Colleges/Gallary/<% ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Name"] %>" />
```

The name bring back the value picName.jpg

Comment: The URL doesn't seem correct `http://p rod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
<img runat="server" src='<%# string.Concat("http://prod:82/en/Colleges/Gallary/", Convert.ToString(((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Name"])) %>' />
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this one too it worked! <%#"http://prod:82/"+((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Name"].ToString()%>